# How to remove fog (added with /fog) in Minecraft bedrock without knowing the user provided ID

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So for context: I had added the end fog to my character but I forgot the user provided ID and now I can’t remove it.
I’ve tried multiple possible IDs I would have used as well as looking online for ways to remove it.
I have a world file editor and have also tried to see if it can be removed from there, but as far as I could tell it can’t .